# List row reset value

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I have a List, with custom Stepper inside each row. Therefore, when I scroll my stepper is reset. (The increment and decrement works when is visible. When it disappear, it's reset. Don't keep the state. It's alway's reset).

> Xcode: v14.2 / Simulator iOS: 16.2

```
struct Product: Codable, Hashable, Identifiable {
  let id: String
  let name: String
  let step: Int
  let quantity: Int
  let priceHT: Double
}

class ProductViewModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var products = [Product]()

  ...
}

struct ProductListView: View {
  @EnvironmentObject var productViewModel: ProductViewModel
  
  var body: some View {
    List(productViewModel.products) { product in
      ProductRowView(product: product)
    }
  }
}
```

My List row:

I tried to modify `@State` with `@binding`, but without success.

```
struct ProductRowView: View {
  @State var product: Product

  var body: some View {
    HStack {
      VStack {
        Text(product.name)
        Text(String(format: "%.2f", product.priceHT) + "€ HT")
      }
        
      Spacer()

      MyStepper(product: $product, value: product.quantity)
        .font(.title)
    }
  }
}
```

My Custom stepper:

```
struct MyStepper: View {
  @Binding var product: Product
  @State var value: Int = 0
   
  var body: some View {
    HStack {
      VStack() {
        HStack {
          Button(action: {
            value -= product.step


            if let row = orderViewModel.productsOrder.firstIndex(where: { $0.name == product.name }) {
              let order = Product(id: product.id, name: product.name, step: product.step, quantity: value, priceHT: product.priceHT)

              if (value == 0) {
                orderViewModel.productsOrder.remove(at: row)
              } else {
                orderViewModel.productsOrder[row] = order
              }
            }
          }, label: {
            Image(systemName: "minus.square.fill")
          })

          Text(value.formatted())

          Button(action: {
            value += product.step

            let order = Product(id: product.id, name: product.name, step: product.step, quantity: value, priceHT: product.priceHT)
                    
            if let row = orderViewModel.productsOrder.firstIndex(where: { $0.name == product.name }) {
              orderViewModel.productsOrder[row] = order
            } else {
              orderViewModel.productsOrder.append(order)
            }
          }, label: {
            Image(systemName: "plus.app.fill")
           })
        }
            
        Text(product.unit)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thks

***EDIT / RESOLVED***

Here is the solution for my case :

Change type of `quantity`. `let` to `var`

```
struct Product: Codable, Hashable, Identifiable {
  ...
  var quantity: Int
  ...
}
```

Delete `@State` in `MyStepper` and replace `value` by `product.quantity`

Comment: You never update the Product in MyStepper, you only change the local `value` property. And all properties in Product are `let` declared which is strange if you want to update it.

Comment: Yes. I want to save in the `view` local state for update to another array `productsOrder`. (`productViewModel.products` is just an initialization)

Comment: You need a list where you can edit the items, something like `List($productViewModel.products) { $product in ...`

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean. 

I have a List in `ProductListView`. `List(productViewModel.products) { product in`

Comment: Look carefully at my code, I use $ signs to say they are editable.

Answer (score 0):

Use bindings for that, e.g.

```
struct ProductListView: View {
  @EnvironmentObject var model: Model
  
  var body: some View {
    List($model.products) { $product in
      ProductRowView(product: $product)
    }
  }
}

struct ProductRowView: View {
  @Binding var product: Product // now you have write access to the Product struct

  ...
```

However, to make the View reusable and to help with previewing, it's best to pass in only the simple types the View needs, e.g.

```
struct TitlePriceView: View {
    let title: String
    @Binding var price: Double
    // etc.
```

```
TitlePriceView(title: product.title, price: $product.price)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I found I solution for my case. Thx